# loop operation inside expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I have a list of about 5 k users that I need to run through the backend command API of a server program in order to retrieve account information. Right now I am doing this via 2 scripts. The first is a bash script that takes each line in a file and feeds the data to the next script, which is an expect script. The expect script then takes the data from the file as an argument and does a telnet to the command API in order to get the data I need. This works fine, but in the spirit of efficiency, and not having to open 5k telnet connections on my server is there any way to loop all of the file data in a single telnet operation inside the expect script?

Bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 exp="/path_to_expect_script"
 file="/path_to_data_file"


 while read -r user; do
 $exp "$user" </dev/tty

 echo

 done < $file
```

Expect Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

lassign $argv user

spawn telnet 127.0.0.1 825
expect "200 PWD Server ready"
send "USER username\r"
expect "300 please send the PASS"
send "PASS password\r"
expect "200 login OK, proceed"
### Line below does the work ####
send "MYCOMMAND $user\r"
expect "200 OK"
send "quit\r"
interact
```

I'd like something like this:

```
send "MYCOMMAND $user\r"
expect "200 OK"
send "MYCOMMAND $user\r"
expect "200 OK"
send "MYCOMMAND $user\r"
expect "200 OK"
etc..
```

How can I do this with expect?

Comment: do you have the priviledge to run *MYCOMMAND user_B* when you login as *user_A*?

Comment: Yes, assuming you are talking about "user_A" being the user that auths to the tellnet session. MYCOMMAND user_B is just a variable thats brought in from the file in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from expect script. As mentioned in the comment, if you have privilege to execute MYCOMMAND for all users.

```
spawn telnet 127.0.0.1 825
expect "200 PWD Server ready"
send "ROOT username\r"
expect "300 please send the PASS"
send "ROOT password\r"
expect "200 login OK, proceed"

set fp [open $file r]
while { [gets $fp user] >= 0 } {  #; Assuming file just contains user names
    send "MYCOMMAND $user\r"
    expect "200 OK"
}

close $fp
send "quit\r"
interact
```

Otherwise you can try to login as new user by modifying the while loop as below

```
while { [gets $fp user] >= 0 } { 
    send "su $user\r"
    expect "300 please send the PASS"
    send "PASS password\r"
    send "MYCOMMAND $user\r"
    expect "200 OK"
}
```

Comment: This *almost* works. One thing I had to change was the "expect "200 ok" to "expect "200 data follow". Here is whats happening. Its performing the action, but every other command it doubles up on the output. MYCOMMAND user
200 data follow
MYCOMMAND user
data I want from first command here
200 data follow
data I want from second command here